# 'Script Too Large' when cloning

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, git

I have a DX project that heavily relies on the [MetadataService](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) class. The files reside in a GitHub repository. I'm trying to figure out why the project fails to get pushed to the scratch org when using git clone.

Here are the steps to re-create it the issue.

```
git clone https://github.com/xxx/repo.git
cd repo
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a scratchTest
sfdx force:source:push -u scratchTest
```

This will generate the following error: Class MetadataService : Script too large: public class MetadataService { public static String SOAP_M_URI = 'h... (31:14)

However if I decide to download the repository as a .ZIP file, extract and push it to the scratch org it works just fine.

I'm struggling to find the root cause of the issue and I'm not sure whether its a sfdx issue or git.

Comment: Do you use Win or *nix? If Win, please check line endings when you push from a cloned repo and from the downloaded one. I'm not sure how sfdx treats them, so I'm just trying to guess. Line endings is one of the common problems with git

Comment: @blank thank you! Git was using CR+LF and that was enough to push the MetadataService.class over the 1MB limit. I've changed back to LF and everything seems to be working fine. For reference here's how I did it:           
 1. git config --global core.eol lf
 2. git config --global core.autocrlf input

Comment: Glad to help! I had a bunch of troubles with line endings, but actually nothing like this. Please, mark the answer I posted as the correct one, so others could find it easily

Comment: The actual solution should be to break this huge file down into multiple. I created an issue in the repo https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/240

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is line endings. Windows uses CR;LF, while *nix uses LF. Obviously, Win line endings use more space.

So the solution is to change all line endings to the *nix one (LF).

I'd actually recommend always use *nix line endings, as they generally produce less problems. To change your git config to use LFs do:

1. `git config --global core.eol lf`
2. `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

This would tell git to prefer LF line endings but to convert them only on commits

**Update**

A more stable solution would be to add the `.gitattributes` file with the following content:

```
* text=auto
*.cls text
```

This would make all the `*.cls` file to get the `LF` line endings on check-in. And will solve the above issue for all users working with the repo.

Comment: The actual solution should be to break this huge file down into multiple. I created an issue in the repo https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/240

Comment: @RobertSösemann, I just posted a comment to your issue (3 years later lol). The real solution is to prevent lineendings change on a repo basis using the .gitattributes file.